# API Documentation - Django Rest Swagger - Different params for GET and POST

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am using **Django Rest Swagger** to document my API which is made with **Django Rest Framework**.
My APIClass has two methods: get and post. And I want the documentation to note this difference but it seems that it expect both to have the same **params**. Look:

This is generating documentation **well**:

```
class Product(APIView):
    """
    Do something with product
    param1 -- Product name
    param2 -- Category
    """

    def get(self, request, format=None):
       ...

    def post(self, request, format=None):
       ...
```

[image: Screenshot2]

But what I want is **this**, which is **not** generating documentation well:

```
class Product(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
       """
       Get products
       param1 -- Parameter for filtering by category
       """
       ...

    def post(self, request, format=None):

       """
       Create a new product
       param1 -- Product name
       param2 -- Category
       """
       ...
```

[image: Screenshot1]

**How can I do it? Any idea??** Thanks so much! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Josep your updated method documentation is correct. The issue you report is well-known in the django-rest-swagger community. See [this commit](https://github.com/ariovistus/django-rest-swagger/commit/bf14ccb6d956314fd6ba5250f06042480e54d2f4) for the fix. Unfortunately Mr. Gibbons has not merged this fix into master, but you can certainly fork and patch as many other people have done.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.